# DNS prefetching and page optimization

Tags: performance, optimization, dns

Today I saw this snippet in the HTML source of a webpage:

```
<!-- prefetch dns -->
<link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//s3.amazonaws.com">
<link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//cdn.api.twitter.com">
<link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//graph.facebook.com">
<link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//connect.facebook.net">
<link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//api.pinterest.com">
<link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//google-analytics.com">
```

How much can you gain by doing this? I haven't seen this before, nor in the [Yahoo! Developer Networks guidelines for optimization](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html). The only thing that seems related is "Reduce DNS Lookups".

In a similar fashion, why doesn't these services expose an IP address to their services and avoid the DNS look-up altogether?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess that this gives parallel DNS lookup of those links later used for a bunch of JavaScript's.

Direct IP-numbers does not work well with CDN's. They resolve to a host close to the caller. If you are in the US they give you the IP of a server in US. If you are in Europe they give you the IP of a server in Europe, etc. You can't cheat like that with direct IP numbers.

Comment: rel="prefetch" “indicates that preemptively fetching and caching the specified resource is likely to be beneficial, as it is highly likely that the user will require this resource.” [...] Mozilla Firefox is the only current browser that supports rel="prefetch". From the "Dive Into HTML 5" book http://diveintohtml5.info/semantics.html